# C++ - Comparación entre nodos

Tags: c++

Tratando de diagramar lo que sucede en la función "doIt" (está completa abajo) me encuentro con una duda puntual a la hora de realizar una comparación.

Duda:
Luego de obtener el último nodo y asignarlo al puntero aux. Veo la siguiente comparación:

```
if(aux == lista)
```

Por un lado: ¿Compara aux -> info y lista -> info?¿Por qué estoy comparando?

Por el otro, luego de

```
aux = obtenerUltimo(lista);
```

¿el diagrama sería así?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como comentario adicional "obtenerUltimo" retorna el último nodo de la lista.
y la estructura del nodo sería:

```
struct Nodo
{
    int info;
    Nodo *sgte;
};
```

La función completa:

```
int doIt(Nodo *&lista)
{
    int elemento;
    Nodo *aux; Nodo *aux2;
    if(lista)
    {
        aux = obtenerUltimo(lista);
        if(aux == lista) // Duda
        {
            elemento = lista -> info;
            delete lista;
            lista = NULL;
            return elemento;
        }
        else
        {
            aux2 = lista;
            while(aux2->sgte != aux)
                aux2 = aux2->sgte;
            elemento = aux -> info;
            delete aux;
            aux -> sgte = NULL;
            return elemento;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error: vacia" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Esa función parece eliminar un nodo _(O varios, dependiendo)_, al hacer `aux == lista` verifica que sea el ultimo nodo para poder eliminarlo y devolver el valor de su respectivo `elemento`, por otra parte, si no se cumple esa condición, entonces solo itera la lista hasta llegar al elemento coincidente con `aux` _(El ultimo)_ y realiza la misma acción. Mi pregunta es: ¿Cuál es tu pregunta al respecto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ¿Compara `aux -> info` y `lista -> info`?

No.

¿Qué tipos son `aux` y `lista`?:

- `lista` es una referencia a puntero a `Nodo` (`Nodo *&lista`).
- `aux` es un puntero a `Nodo` (`Nodo *aux`).

A efectos prácticos [una referencia se comporta igual que el tipo al que referencia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46909/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-int-e-int/46931#46931), así que `aux == lista` está comparando dos punteros que no es más que comparar la dirección de memoria que contienen, no el contenido de aquello a lo que están apuntando.

En otras palabras, la expresión `aux == lista` será verdadera si tanto `aux` como `lista` están almacenando la misma dirección de memoria.

> ¿Por qué estoy comparando?

Tú sabrás, es tu código. Yo al leerlo no le veo mucho sentido, al menos debería tener sentido para ti que lo has desarrollado.

> ¿Tras obtener el último `Nodo` el diagrama sería así?
>
> [image]

Suponiendo que `obtenerUltimo` haga lo que dices que hace: Si. Pero veamos qué sucede luego, primero supongamos que `aux` y `lista` apuntan al mismo `Nodo`:

[image]

En tu código, guardas `elemento` en una variable para devolverlo luego, borras el `Nodo` apuntado por `lista`, haces que apunte a `NULL` y devuelve `elemento`; tras estos pasos tu memoria quedaría parecida a esto:

[image]

Como puedes ver, el penúltimo `Nodo` se queda apuntando al `Nodo` borrado, asumo que esto será un problema pues dicho `Nodo` no ha sido informado de que su siguiente ha dejado de existir.

Cuando `aux` y `lista` no apuntan al mismo `Nodo`, haces avanzar otro puntero auxiliar (`aux2`) hasta quedarte en el nodo anterior a `aux`, seguidamente guardas `elemento` en una variable para devolverlo luego, borras el `Nodo` apuntado por `aux`, haces que (¡después de borrarlo!) su siguiente apunte a `NULL` y devuelves `elemento`. Este código fallará en tiempo de ejecución en la orden `aux -> sgte = NULL;`. Pero suponiendo que no fallase, partiendo de tu diagrama inicial, tras estos pasos tu memoria quedaría parecida a esto:

[image]

No sólo es erróneo por acceder a memoria borrada (`delete aux; aux -> sgte = NULL;`) si no que además el nodo que apunta `aux2` tampoco ha sido informado de que su siguiente ha dejado de existir.