# Duda sobre la clase vector

Tags: c++, array, c++11

En un array el nombre del array es un puntero al array. Por lo que en `iArray` y `&iArray[0]` se obtiene el mismo valor. Lo que no entiendo muy bien, es que esta sucediendo cuando trato de repetir esto mismo con `myvector`.

```
int iArray[]={1,2,3,4};
cout<<iArray<<endl;
cout<<&iArray[0]<<endl;

std::vector<int> myvector={1,2,3,4};
cout<<myvector<<endl;
```

Esta última sentencia, devuelve el siguiente error:

```
 ..\YourOtherClass_test.cpp:40:9: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'std::vector<int>')
```

Si trato el nombre, como referencias.Es decir:

```
cout<<&myvector<<endl;
cout<<&myvector[0]<<endl;
```

Me imprime direcciones diferentes. ¿Trabajando con vectores, hay alguna forma de saber donde esta el elemento 0, por el nombre del vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que `std::vector` es una clase que, internamente, hace uso de un array, pero tiene muchas más cosas.

Un array crudo como el que usas en el primer ejemplo no tiene más que la memoria necesaria para almacenar el número de elmentos que le estás pidiendo:

```
                | 0x100 | 0x101 | 0x102 | 0x103 | 0x104 | 0x105 | 0x106 |0x107 |
int array[2] -> |             array[0]          |             array[1]         |
```

Sin embargo la clase `std::vector` es más compleja (y  de ahí que sea mucho más versátil que un array crudo. El estándar no especifica cómo debe estar implementada esta clase, en el caso de MSVC2015 podemos encontrar una estructura como esta (simplificando):

```
template<class _Ty, class _Ax = allocator<_Ty> >
class vector
{
  typedef typename _Ax::template rebind<_Ty>::other _Alty;
  typedef typename _Alty::pointer pointer;

  pointer _Myfirst; // pointer to beginning of array
  pointer _Mylast;  // pointer to current end of sequence
  pointer _Myend;   // pointer to end of array
  _Alty _Alval; // allocator object for values
};
```

Que básicamente nos viene a decir que, para este compilador en concreto, la clase `std::vector` gestiona tres punteros (inicio del array, final de secuencia y final del array) y un objeto para la gestión de la memoria.

`std::vector` usa punteros internamente porque, a diferencia de un array crudo, hace uso de memoria dinámica. Esto explica por qué puedes empezar a añadir elementos al vector sin preocuparte por su tamaño:

```
std::vector<int> datos;
// ...
datos.push_back(10);
datos.push_back(20);
datos.push_back(30);
// ...
```

Mientras que con un array crudo has de tener mucho cuidado para no exceder sus límites:

```
int array[10];
array[10] = 123; // <<--- ups!!!
```

Se ve claramente que un array crudo y `std::vector`, aunque puedan usarse con la misma sintaxis, se parecen como un churro a un cohete espacial.

Ahora bien, respondiendo a tus preguntas...

> Si trato el nombre, como referencias ... Me imprime direcciones diferentes

Efectivamente:

- `&myvector`  te va a devolver la dirección de memoria donde se encuentra el objeto `std::vector` actual.
- `&myvector[0]` devuelve la dirección de memoria donde se encuentra el primer elemento del vector. Como la clase `std::vector` hace uso de memoria dinámica, esta posición de memoria dificilmente va a coincidir con la obtenida en el punto anterior.

> ¿Trabajando con vectores, hay alguna forma de saber donde esta el elemento 0, por el nombre del vector?

¿Y para qué quieres saber ese dato exactamente?

Si necesitas modificar únicamente esa posición puedes obtenerla como has hecho en tu ejemplo:

```
`&myvector[0]`
```

Pero usar el vector así implica ciertos riesgos totalmente innecesarios:

- Si necesitas modificar elementos del vector lo más facil y seguro es pasar el vector como referencia:

  ```
  void func(std::vector<int> & myvector)
  {
    // ...
  }
  ```
- La clase `vector` es capaz de redimensionar la memoria que gestiona de forma totalmente automática y transparente para el usuario. Si accedes a sus posiciones de memoria como pretendes y el vector se redimensiona puedes acabar accediendo a memoria que no te pertenece.
- Para moverte por el vector lo más común es usar los iteradores:

  ```
  std::vector<int> myvector = funcionQueGeneraUnVector();

  // Hasta C++11
  for( std::vector<int>::iterator it = myvector.begin(); it != myvector.end(); ++it )
  {
    // ...
  }

  // C++11 en adelante
  for( auto it = std::begin(myvector); it != std::end(myvector); ++it )
  {
    // ...
  }
  ```

  Los iteradores se pueden usar de mil maneras diferentes:

  ```
  std::vector<int> datos = { 1, 4, 2, 7, 5, 9, 3, 0 };

  // Localizamos la posicion del numero 7
  auto it = std::find(std::begin(datos),std::end(datos),7);

  // Imprimimos dicho valor, despues el anterior y finalmente el posterior
  std::cout << *it << *(it-1) << *(it+1) << '\n';

  // Eliminamos el numero 7 del vector
  datos.erase(it);

  // Imprimimos el vector sin el 7
  for( int numero : datos )
    std::cout << numero << ' ';
  ```

> Esta última sentencia, devuelve el siguiente error:
>
> ```
> ..\YourOtherClass_test.cpp:40:9: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'std::vector<int>')
> ```

Eso es porque **no existe** una sobrecarga del operador de inserción sobre la clase `ostream` que acepte un objeto de tipo `std::vector`. Sin embargo eso es algo que tiene solución:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::vector<int> const& v)
{
  for( int dato : v )
    os << dato << ' ';
  return os;
}

std::vector<int> myvector={1,2,3,4};
cout<<myvector<<endl; // Imprime 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 3):

Me encanta el chocolate, ¡Pero no entiendo por qué no lo puedo comer sin desenvolverlo!.

[image]

Te pasa exáctamente lo mismo con `std::vector`.

---

La clase `std::vector` es un envoltorio sobre un espacio de memoria dinámica, pero no es ese espacio de memoria y por lo tanto no actuará como si lo fuera.

Cuando ejecutas este código:

```
int iArray[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
std::cout << iArray << '\n';
```

No te va a mostrar `1` si no una dirección de memoria que (como bien has señalado) coincidirá con `&iArray[0]`. En cambio este código...

```
std::vector<int> myvector = {1, 2, 3, 4};
std::cout << myvector << '\n';
```

... está pidiendo pasar a `std::cout` el envoltorio, no la memoria que dicho envoltorio está gestionando. Puedes conseguir el efecto de "pasar la dirección de memoria del primer elemento" así:

```
std::vector<int> myvector = {1, 2, 3, 4};
std::cout << myvector.data() << '\n';
```

La función [`std::vector::data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) devuelve el puntero a la memoria manejada por el `std::vector`. Conseguirás el mismo efecto así:

```
std::vector<int> myvector = {1, 2, 3, 4};
std::cout << &myvector[0] << '\n';
```

Ya que `std::vector` ofrece un [operador de indexado](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) que devuelve una referencia al elemento cuyo índice pases en los corchetes, y solicitar la [dirección de memoria de una referencia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46909/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-int-e-int/46931#46931) es como solicitarla del objeto refereciado. Pero si lo quieres hacer exactamente igual que con una formación<sup>1</sup> deberás crear un operador de inyección en flujo de datos (`<<`) sobre el `std::vector`:

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream operator <<(std::ostream &out, const std::vector<T> &v)
{
    return (out << v.data());
}

int main()
{
    int iArray[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::cout << iArray << '\n';
    std::cout << &iArray[0] << '\n';

    std::vector<int> myvector = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    // Correcto, llama al operador que creamos antes
    std::cout << myvector << '\n';
    std::cout << &myvector[0] << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

---

1. También conocida como arreglo, o en inglés array.