# Lista enlazada por referencia a un metodo, c++

Tags: c++, lista, punteros

Ando necesitando ayuda. Estoy intentando leer un archivo csv pasar los campos a una lista enlazada y de ahí pasarla como referencia a algunos métodos en una clase.

```
while(linea!=VACIO){
    Lista<std::string>*datosCultivo;
    cultivos.datosLista(linea, datosCultivo);
    cargarCultivosJugador(datosCultivo);
    datosCultivo=NULL;
}
void Jugador::cargarCultivosJugador(Lista<std::string>*datos){
    std::string tipoSemilla=datos->obtener(1).c_str();
    std::cout<<tipoSemilla<<std::endl;
    if(tipoSemilla=="A"){
        //this->cultivos->tipoA->agregarInfo(datos);
    }
    else if(tipoSemilla=="B"){
        this->cultivos->tipoB->agregarInfo(datos);
    }
    else if(tipoSemilla=="C"){
        this->cultivos->tipoC->agregarInfo(datos);
    }
    else{
        std::cout<<"No se cargaron los cultivos..."<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

`datosLista` me carga bien los campos en la lista, el problema viene cuando la paso a `cargarCultivosJugador`.

Entra en el método pero al ir a agregarInfo pierde la referencia y se sale de rango(No llega a imprimir nada dentro de ese método y debería obtener valores de la lista y agregarlos a un puntero objeto). Aclaro que no subo todo el código porque es muy extenso. La verdad nosé como pasarle el tamaño de la lista por parámetro ¿o debería replantearme el problema? No dispongo de mucho tiempo para esto ultimo, cualquier ayuda es bienvenida. Saludos

Comment: No estoy seguro de haber entendido bien, pero el tipo: `Lista<std::string>` tiene el método [size](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/size) que te retorna el tamaño de la lista; así que no habría necesidad de pasarlo por valor or referencia.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, pásate por el [tour] y [ask] para hacerte una idea acerca de lo que se espera de las preguntas aquí (y así además ganarás tu primera medalla). A modo de resumen, sería interesante que incluyeses la interfaz de la clase `Lista`. Así podríamos darte respuestas más o menos certeras

Answer (score 2):

#### No tienes claros conceptos básicos de C++.

No estás pasando la lista por referencia si no por dirección. Además estás pasando una dirección de memoria que no apunta a ninguna lista, pero además es un puntero diferente a cada vuelta del bucle y para colmo los pasas a una función que parece no existir.

#### Tu bucle.

Veamos que sucede realmente en tu bucle:

```
/* 1 */ while(linea!=VACIO){
/* 2 */     Lista<std::string>*datosCultivo;
/* 3 */     cultivos.datosLista(linea, datosCultivo);
/* 4 */     cargarCultivosJugador(datosCultivo);
/* 5 */     datosCultivo=NULL;
/* 6 */ }
```

1. No se que es `línea` ni `VACIO`, asumiré que funciona.
2. Creas un **puntero** a un objeto plantilla llamado `Lista`, este puntero **no apunta a ningún objeto existente**.
3. Llamas a la función miembro `datosLista` de un objeto llamado `cultivos` cuyo tipo desconocemos, asumiré que funciona.
4. Llamas a la función `cargarCultivosJugador` pasando el puntero que no apunta a ningún objeto, esta función **no es** la que muestras debajo, ya que no se está llamando asociada a a ninguna instancia del objeto `Jugador`.
5. Haces que el puntero que no apuntaba a ningún objeto existente apunte a `null`.
6. Finaliza el bucle, **todas las variables del ámbito son destruidas**, así que `datosCultivo` deja de existir.

#### ¿Cómo se pasa por referencia?

Echa un vistazo a [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/46931/2742), después observa los cambios en tu código:

```
// Los datosCultivo deben existir FUERA del bucle, para tener persistencia
Lista<std::string> datosCultivo;
// Jugador j;

while(linea!=VACIO){
    cultivos.datosLista(linea, datosCultivo);
    // cargarCultivosJugador se llama sobre una instancia de Jugador
    j.cargarCultivosJugador(datosCultivo);
}

//           Recibe una referencia, no un puntero ---> v
void Jugador::cargarCultivosJugador(Lista<std::string> &datos){
    //       Punto, no flecha ---> v
    std::string tipoSemilla = datos.obtener(1);
    std::cout << tipoSemilla << '\n';

    if(tipoSemilla=="A"){
        //this->cultivos->tipoA->agregarInfo(datos);
    }
    else if(tipoSemilla=="B"){
        this->cultivos->tipoB->agregarInfo(datos);
    }
    else if(tipoSemilla=="C"){
        this->cultivos->tipoC->agregarInfo(datos);
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "No se cargaron los cultivos...\n";
    }
}
```