# Ampersand delante de método

Tags: c++

he visto un ampersand delante de un método de una clase y no se realmente para que sirve, por ejemplo aquí:

```
Persona& operator=(const Persona& p);
```

¿Para que sirve este ampersand?

Comment: Relacionada: [¿Cual es la diferencia entre int * e int &?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/46909/19610)

Comment: No es "delante de un método", es "detrás de un tipo/clase".