# Error: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wpedantic]

Tags: c++, sqlite, sql

Al intentar compilar el archivo, me aparece el error mencionado en el título.
***error: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wpedantic] en la línea 28 del fichero.** 
 Adjunto el código.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "sqlite3.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    sqlite3 *db;
    char *error = 0;
    int res;
    char *sql;

    /* Open database */
    res = sqlite3_open("prob.db", &db);
    if (res)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "No se pudo abrir base de datos: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Base de datos OK\n");
    }

    sql = "CREATE TABLE events ("
          "'timestamp' DATETIME, "
          "'level' NUMBER, "
          "'type' NUMBER, "
          "'message' TEXT)"; //En esta linea figura el error

    res = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, 0, &error);
    if (res != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", error);
        sqlite3_free(error);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "Tabla creada!\n");
    }

    sqlite3_close(db);

    return 0;
}
```

Quisiera saber que es lo que puede estar ocasionando este problema. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4):

El mensaje de error, en traducción libre, viene a decir:

> error: El estandar ISO prohibe asignar una cadena literal a un `char *`

Y eso es sencillamente lo que te está pasando: `"CREATE TABLE events ..."` es una cadena literal; el lenguaje dicta que las cadenas literales **no se pueden modificar**. Y tú, al usar un `char *`, **podrías intentar modificarlas**.

Si echamos una mirada a la función [`sqlite3_exec( )`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html), vemos que su prototipo es:

> int sqlite3_exec(
>     sqlite3*,
>     const char *sql,
>     int (*callback)(void*,int,char**,char**),
>     void *,
>     char **errmsg
>   );

Su segundo argumento es del tipo `const char *`, es decir, espera una cadena constante que **no se modificará** dentro de la función.

Pues listo. No hay ningún motivo para usar un `char *` (puntero a cadena que podemos modificar). Por lo tanto, nos basta con hacer

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  sqlite3 *db;
  char *error = 0;
  int res;
  const char *sql;
  ...
```

Nos basta con cambiar el tipo de tu variable `sql` a `const char *sql`.

Answer (score 1):

El error es claro y conciso, tal vez no lo entiendas por estar en inglés, permíteme traducirlo:

> Error: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*'

> Error: [ISO](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organizaci%C3%B3n_Internacional_de_Normalizaci%C3%B3n) C++ prohíbe convertir una cadena constante a 'char*'

---

En tu código tienes una cadena constante:

```
"CREATE TABLE events ("
"'timestamp' DATETIME, "
"'level' NUMBER, "
"'type' NUMBER, "
"'message' TEXT)"
```

El tipo de esta cadena es `const char[90]`, fíjate que es `const`ante. [No puedes apuntar a datos constantes con punteros no constantes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/46931/2742). Para solucionar el error, simplemente declara `sql` como puntero a datos constantes:

```
const char *sql;
~~~~~
```