# No puedo leer un archivo PPM en c++

Tags: c++, imagen, cmake

soy nuevo por aquí, lo que pasa es que tengo que leer un archivo (una imagen) PPM mediante un programa de C++, estoy usando QT Creator y el programa lo creé usando CMAKE a partir de un archivo CMakeLists.txt. En el CMakeLists coloqué todas las carpetas que necesito al igual que los .h y.c que voy a utilizar, sin embargo, cuando intento leer desde el main la imagen, me saltan dos errores. Si estoy incluyendo el archivo de cabecera en el main.

Este es el archivo CMakeLists.txt

```
project(testc LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(testc_src
    "test/main.cpp"
    "include/ppm.h"
    "source/ppm.c"

)

add_executable(testc ${testc_src})
include_directories ( ./include)
```

El archivo de cabecera .h

```
 *
 * ppm.h
 *
 * Read and write PPM files.  Only works for "raw" format.
 *
 * AF970205
 *
 ****************************************************************/

#ifndef PPM_H
#define PPM_H

#include <sys/types.h>

#define u_char unsigned char

typedef struct Image //crea un nuevo tipo Image de tipo struct
{
  int width;
  int height;
  u_char *data;
} Image;//crea una variable imagen

Image *ImageCreate(int width, int height);
Image *ImageRead(const char *filename);
void   ImageWrite(Image *image, const char *filename);

int    ImageWidth(Image *image);
int    ImageHeight(Image *image);

void   ImageClear(Image *image, u_char red, u_char green, u_char blue);

void   ImageSetPixel(Image *image, int x, int y, int chan, u_char val);
u_char ImageGetPixel(Image *image, int x, int y, int chan);

#endif /* PPM_H */
```

El archivo .c

```
 *
 * ppm.c
 *
 * Read and write PPM files.  Only works for "raw" format.
 *
 * AF970205
 *
 ****************************************************************/


#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "ppm.h"
#include <sys/types.h>

#define u_char unsigned char


/************************ private functions ****************************/

/* die gracelessly */

static void
die(char *message)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "ppm: %s\n", message);
  exit(1);
}


/* check a dimension (width or height) from the image file for reasonability */

static void
checkDimension(int dim)
{
  if (dim < 1 || dim > 4000) //si es muy grande o tiene valores negativos el archivo no abre
    die("file contained unreasonable width or height");
}


/* read a header: verify format and get width and height */

static void
readPPMHeader(FILE *fp, int *width, int *height)
{
  char ch;
  int  maxval;

  if (fscanf(fp, "P%c\n", &ch) != 1 || ch != '6') //si fscanf retorna un numero diferente de 1 entonces falla la función. Si el numero que acompaña a la P no es el 6 no es PPM
    die("file is not in ppm raw format; cannot read");

  /* skip comments */
  ch = getc(fp);
  while (ch == '#')
    {
      do {
        ch = getc(fp);
      } while (ch != '\n'); /* read to the end of the line Lee hasta que el dato sea \n*/
      ch = getc(fp);            /* Continua leyendo en la siguiente linea*/
    }

  if (!isdigit(ch)) die("cannot read header information from ppm file"); //Si lo que se lee no es un numero, entonces se generar un error

  ungetc(ch, fp);       /* put that digit back Se devuelve una posición para leer de nuevo el número*/

  /* read the width, height, and maximum value for a pixel */
  fscanf(fp, "%d%d%d\n", width, height, &maxval);

  if (maxval != 255) die("image is not true-color (24 bit); read failed");

  checkDimension(*width);
  checkDimension(*height);
}

/************************ exported functions ****************************/ //Funciones que vienen del .h

Image *
ImageCreate(int width, int height) //Crea la imagen, asigna o reserva espacios de memoria para crear la imagen
{
  Image *image = (Image *) malloc(sizeof(Image));

  if (!image) die("cannot allocate memory for new image");

  image->width  = width;
  image->height = height;
  image->data   = (u_char *) malloc(width * height * 3);

  if (!image->data) die("cannot allocate memory for new image");

  return image;
}


Image *
ImageRead(const char *filename)
{
  int width, height, num, size;
  u_char *p;

  Image *image = (Image *) malloc(sizeof(Image));
  FILE  *fp    = fopen(filename, "r");

  if (!image) die("cannot allocate memory for new image");
  if (!fp)    die("cannot open file for reading");

  readPPMHeader(fp, &width, &height);

  size          = width * height * 3;
  image->data   = (u_char *) malloc(size);
  image->width  = width;
  image->height = height;

  if (!image->data) die("cannot allocate memory for new image");

  num = fread((void *) image->data, 1, (size_t) size, fp);

  if (num != size) die("cannot read image data from file");

  fclose(fp);

  return image;
}


void ImageWrite(Image *image, const char *filename)
{
  int num;
  int size = image->width * image->height * 3;

  FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "w");

  if (!fp) die("cannot open file for writing");

  fprintf(fp, "P6\n%d %d\n%d\n", image->width, image->height, 255);

  num = fwrite((void *) image->data, 1, (size_t) size, fp);

  if (num != size) die("cannot write image data to file");

  fclose(fp);
}


int
ImageWidth(Image *image)
{
  return image->width;
}


int
ImageHeight(Image *image)
{
  return image->height;
}


void
ImageClear(Image *image, u_char red, u_char green, u_char blue)
{
  int i;
  int pix = image->width * image->height;

  u_char *data = image->data;

  for (i = 0; i < pix; i++)
    {
      *data++ = red;
      *data++ = green;
      *data++ = blue;
    }
}

void
ImageSetPixel(Image *image, int x, int y, int chan, u_char val)
{
  int offset = (y * image->width + x) * 3 + chan;

  image->data[offset] = val;
}


u_char
ImageGetPixel(Image *image, int x, int y, int chan)
{
  int offset = (y * image->width + x) * 3 + chan;

  return image->data[offset];
}
```

El programa principal main.cpp

```
#include "ppm.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Image *image;
    const char *filename="Data/uno.ppm";
    image = ImageRead(filename);
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Todos los archivos están en sus carpetas correspondientes pero cuando intento leer la imagen los errores que me aparecen son:  `ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings] char *filename="Data/uno.ppm"; //const`

Y luego que "ImageRead" no está definida pero sí está definida:

`` error: undefined reference to `ImageRead(char*)' ``

¿Qué puedo hacer para leer la imagen? Gracias por su ayuda!!!

PD: El código nos lo entregaron de una página web y debemos arreglarlo, pero no encuentro por qué no funciona. Gracias de nuevo.

Edit 1: El código actual se encuentra actualizado según el comentario que colocó braver anteriormente. Se cambiaron todas las funciones que tenían char por const char sin embargo aún aparece el siguiente error: `` error: undefined reference to `ImageRead(char const*)' ``

Comment: Te falta agregar C a la lista de lenguajes del proyecto (`project(testc LANGUAGES CXX C)` ) para que CMake no ignore los archivos de C y los compile. La otra advertencia que te sale esta respondida en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/283444/error-iso-c-forbids-converting-a-string-constant-to-char-wpedantic).

Comment: @braver Listo, añadí lo que dijiste al cmakelist. Agradezco tu ayuda; ya había leído la otra pregunta sin embargo, cuando coloco el const char me aparece este error `error: undefined reference to ImageRead(char const*)'` Ya cambié todos los char que aparecía en las funciones por const char en todos los archivos pero aún así no puede compilar. Voy a actualizar el código para que veas los cambios. ¿Dónde debería añadir el "const"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falto envolver el **include** en un `extern "C" {}`:

```
extern "C" {
#include "ppm.h"
}

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Image *image;
    const char *filename="Data/uno.ppm";
    image = ImageRead(filename);
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Se necesita hacerlo al incluir encabezados de bibliotecas de C, porque el
enlazador de C++ usa una convención de nombres diferente que en C (en C++ se "mutilan"
para soportar la sobrecarga de funciones que en C no existe).