# Paso de valores por referencia en una PILA en C

Tags: c++

Tengo esta estructura y esta función, iniciando mi puntero de tipo Nodo en NULL:

```
struct Nodo{
   int dato;
   Nodo *siguiente;
};

Nodo *tope=NULL;

void agregarNodo(Nodo *tope, int dato){

   Nodo *nuevoNodo = new Nodo();
   nuevoNodo->dato= dato;
   nuevoNodo->siguiente=tope;
   tope=nuevoNodo;

}
```

Compila, pero no se amarran mis punteros, osea que cuando vuelvo a llamar la funcion para agregar otro nuevo nodo a la pila, **el puntero *tope vuelve a valer null o cero en vez de sostener la direccion del nodo que se creo anteriormente.**

No deberia pasar esto ya que *tope deberia mantener la direccion de memoria del nodo anterior gracias a este amarre:

```
nuevoNodo->siguiente=tope;
tope=nuevoNodo;
```

Comment: Te sugiero consultar [¿ Cual es la diferencia entre `int *` e `int &` ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/46909/19610).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos a ver lo que pasa paso a paso:

```
Nodo *tope = NULL;
```

Creas una variable de tipo `puntero a Nodo` y la inicializas con `NULL`.

```
void agregarNodo( Nodo *tope, int dato ) {
```

Entramos en una función que recibe **una copia** de un `puntero a Nodo` y **una copia** de un `int`.

```
  Nodo *nuevoNodo = new Nodo( );
  nuevoNodo->dato = dato;
  nuevoNodo->siguiente=tope;
```

Haces *cositas* dentro de la función.

```
  tope = nuevoNodo;
}
```

Asignas un valor **a la copia** que recibiste como argumento en tu función.

La clave aquí es el concepto de **copia**. **No** recibes `tope`, recibes **una copia** de `tope`. Por lo que tu variable original se queda **exactamente como estaba**, `== NULL`.

Una posible solución es utilizando referencias. Vamos a verlo paso a paso también:

```
Nodo *tope = NULL;
```

Creas una variable de tipo `puntero a Nodo` y la inicializas con `NULL`.

```
void agregarNodo( Nodo *&tope, int dato ) {
```

Entramos en una función que recibe **una referencia** a un `puntero a Nodo` y **una copia** de un `int`.

```
  Nodo *nuevoNodo = new Nodo( );
  nuevoNodo->dato = dato;
  nuevoNodo->siguiente=tope;
```

Haces *cositas* dentro de la función.

```
  tope = nuevoNodo;
}
```

Asignas un valor **a la referencia** que recibiste como argumento en tu función.

La clave aquí es el concepto de **referencia**. Ahora, es como si recibieras directamente a `tope`, por lo que tu variable original **si** refleja los cambios.