# si x es una variable, que se guarda con la siguiente instruccion?

Tags: c++, variables, paso-por-referencia

¿Que representa este `element& el1 = x`? porque la direccion de memoria esta guardando una variable, no entiendo.

```
  element_concrete_1 x;
  element_concrete_2 y;

  element& el1 = x;
  element& el2 = y;
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cual es la diferencia entre \`int \*\` e \`int &\`?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46909/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-int-e-int)

Comment: El identificador `el1` es una referencia, por lo tanto, se refiere a la misma dirección de memoria donde esté alojada la variable `x`. Esto quiere decir, que `el1` no ocupa memoria, es simplemente un alias de la dirección de memoria de la variable `x`.

Answer (score -1):

Esto le ayuda a los programadores a saber en que espacio en memoria se alojo tu variable. Muchas de las veces sirve para optimizar tus programas, ya sea para que quieras liberar la memoria cuando ya no ocupes la variable o manejar a bajo nivel estructuras de datos como lista enlazadas, grafos...