# ¿Por qué se necesitan punteros para hacer que un campo de un struct apunte hacia otro struct?

Tags: c++, struct

#### Introducción

El título es un poco confuso, pero trataré de ayudarte a entender mejor de que tratará mi pregunta...

Pongamos un ejemplo:

Quiero que un campo de un `struct` apunte hacia otro `struct` (esto es muy parecido a la [recursividad](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursi%C3%B3n)).

Entonces, he visto en algunas partes que se necesita un puntero para poder hacer esa tarea. Y yo me pregunto: ¿Por qué se necesita punteros para hacer eso?

#### ¿Qué he intentado por ahora?

He buscado [C Video Tutorial 6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MjQ6PEQen-Q&list=PLGLfVvz_LVvSaXCpKS395wbCcmsmgRea7&index=7) de [Derek Banas](https://www.youtube.com/user/derekbanas), ya que el enseña excelentemente bien. Ví el video entero y nunca explicó porque se necesitan los punteros (o tal vez lo explicó en otro video).

#### Código

Pueden tomar esta estructura de ejemplo para explicarme:

```
struct nodo{
 int dato;
 nodo* siguiente; // Aquí está lo que no entiendo.
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para instanciar un dato el compilador debe saber cuánto ocupa. El compilador no sabe cuánto ocupa un dato hasta que éste se define; una definición de objeto se completa al cerrar sus llaves:

```
struct nodo // Esto declara el objeto
{
    int dato;
}; // Aquí el objeto está definido.
```

Sabemos que el objeto `nodo` ocupará lo mismo que ocupe un `int`, que es su único miembro, si añadimos un objeto del mismo tipo a la definición obtendremos un error:

```
struct nodo // Esto declara el objeto
{
    int dato;
    nodo siguiente; // Error, 'nodo' no está definido!
}; // Aquí el objeto está definido.
```

Obtenemos el error porque en el momento en que queremos usar `nodo`, su definición aún no ha acabado y el compilador no podrá saber cuánto ocupa.

Pero si usamos punteros el problema se soluciona, el compilador siempre sabe lo que ocupa un puntero a un dato arbitrario, ¡incluso punteros a datos que aún no están definidos!

```
struct nodo // Esto declara el objeto
{
    int dato;
    nodo *siguiente; // Aquí aún no sabe lo que es 'nodo', pero sabe que puede apuntar a ello
}; // Aquí el objeto está definido.
```

Pero el puntero no es el único dato que tiene esta característica, también puedes referenciar objetos sin definir:

```
struct nodo // Esto declara el objeto
{
    int dato;
    nodo &siguiente; // Aquí aún no sabe lo que es 'nodo', pero sabe que puede referenciar a ello
}; // Aquí el objeto está definido.
```

El problema es que las referencias deben referenciar algo, los punteros no (Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/46931/2742) para saber más del tema), así que aunque la estructura anterior compile, no puede ser instanciada:

```
struct nodo // Esto declara el objeto
{
    int dato;
    nodo &siguiente; // Aquí aún no sabe lo que es 'nodo', pero sabe que puede referenciar a ello
}; // Aquí el objeto está definido.

int main()
{
    nodo n; // Error, 'n.siguiente' debe ser inicializado
    return 0;
}
```

Ahora podemos responder a la pregunta "*¿Por qué se necesitan punteros para hacer que un campo de un struct apunte **hacia un struct del mismo tipo**?*":

Porque no se puede usar una instancia (ya que el objeto no está definido) ni se puede usar una referencia (porque requiere inicialización), así pues sólo es posible usar punteros.