# ¿Por que si cambio *& por solo el * el programa sigue funcionando?

Tags: c++, punteros, paso-por-referencia

Este es un código de agregar pilas, lo que no logro entender bien es que en el prototipo de la función le estoy pasando el *& mi pregunta es ¿por que si solo uso el * el código sigue funcionando sin necesidad de usar *& , hay alguna diferencia entre usar * y *& ?Gracias.

```
#include<iostream>

struct Nodo{
    int dato;
    Nodo *siguiente;
};

void agregar_pila(Nodo *&, int);

using namespace std;

int main(){

    Nodo *pila = NULL;
    
    agregar_pila(pila, 6);
    agregar_pila(pila, 12);

    return 0;
}

void agregar_pila(Nodo *&pila, int n){
    Nodo *nuevo_nodo = new Nodo();
    nuevo_nodo->dato = n;
    nuevo_nodo->siguiente = pila;
    pila = nuevo_nodo;

    cout<<"Elemento "<<n<<" agregado correctamente a la pila"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cual es la diferencia entre \`int \*\` e \`int &\`?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46909/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-int-e-int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: Si quitas ese `&`, el programa, aunque no de errores, **dejará de funcionar correctamente**, como demostraré luego.

### Qué hace el `&`?

Hay que comenzar diciendo que el código es C++. No compilaría correctamente con un compilador de C. En C no se admite el poner un `&` como parte de la declaración de un parámetro.

En C++ el poner `&` delante de un parámetro indica que éste se pasa *por referencia*. Así pues, en tu función:

```
void agregar_pila(Nodo *&pila, int n){
   ...
}
```

el parámetro `pila` es de tipo "referencia a puntero a Nodo". Esto quiere decir que la variable que le vayas a pasar como parámetro ha de ser de tipo "puntero a nodo", pero la funcion lo que recibirá será una referencia al puntero que le pases.

Eso es lo que permite que dentro de la función, cuando haces:

```
    pila = nuevo_nodo;
```

estés modificando la variable que habías recibido como parámetro, en vez de una copia de esa variable que sería lo que ocurriría si no fuera de tipo referencia.

En definitiva, cuando el programa principal llama a esa función por ejemplo aquí:

```
    agregar_pila(pila, 6);
```

la variable `pila` de la función `main()` es pasada como referencia a `agregar_pila()`, por lo que la variable `pila` dentro de esa función *alterará directamente* la variable `pila` de `main()`.

Como consecuencia, una vez que la función retorne, la variable `pila` de `main()` habrá cambiado de valor. Esto podemos verificarlo imprimiendo esa variable:

```
int main(){

    Nodo *pila = NULL;
    
    cout << pila << endl;

    agregar_pila(pila, 6);
    cout << pila << endl;

    agregar_pila(pila, 12);
    cout << pila << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Al ejecutarlo veremos:

```
0
Elemento 6 agregado correctamente a la pila
0x2383280
Elemento 12 agregado correctamente a la pila
0x23832a0
```

Como ves, cada vez que se llama a la función, la variable `pila` cambia de valor, como debe ser para apuntar al nuevo elemento insertado en la cabeza de la pila.

### ¿Y si no ponemos &?

Si no se pone `&` el programa compila y ejecuta sin errores, pero **no funciona correctamente**. Al no poner `&` la variable no se pasa por referencia, sino por copia. Esto implica que la variable `pila` de la función `agregar_pila()` es una variable independiente de la variable `pila` del programa principal.

Así cuando en la función haces `pila=nuevo_nodo;` estás modificando sólo la variable local de la función `agregar_pila()`, pero la variable `pila` de `main()` permanecerá inalterada.

En efecto, si pruebas a ejecutar el mismo experimento de antes pero quitando el `&` en el parámetro (no hace falta ni siquiera modificar `main()`), verás que ahora imprime:

```
0
Elemento 6 agregado correctamente a la pila
0
Elemento 12 agregado correctamente a la pila
0
```

O sea, la variable `pila` de `main()` sigue valiendo siempre `NULL`. Por ello, aunque el dato se inserta, no se actualiza el puntero a la cabeza de la cola, con lo que la implementación no es correcta.

### Bonus: implementación en C (sin `&`)

Ya que C no tiene la posibilidad de marcar como "referencia" un parámetro ¿cómo se podría lograr esto mismo? (es decir, que la función modifique una variable que en realidad pertenece a `main()`)

La solución es que en lugar de pasar el puntero `pila` a la función, le pasemos *la dirección en que se halla el puntero `pila`*, es decir `&pila`. De ese modo la función no recibiría ya un puntero a `Nodo`, sino la dirección de un puntero a `Nodo`, es decir, un *puntero a puntero a `Nodo`*. A través de esa dirección podrá modificar el puntero original.

La cosa sería entonces así:

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct Nodo{
    int dato;
    Nodo *siguiente;
};

void agregar_pila(Nodo **, int);

int main(){

    Nodo *pila = NULL;
    
    printf("%p\n", pila);
    agregar_pila(&pila, 6);
    printf("%p\n", pila);

    agregar_pila(&pila, 12);
    printf("%p\n", pila);

    return 0;
}

void agregar_pila(Nodo **pila, int n){ // <--- Atención al doble asterisco
    Nodo *nuevo_nodo = new Nodo();
    nuevo_nodo->dato = n;
    nuevo_nodo->siguiente = *pila;   // <--- Atención al asterisco aqui
    *pila = nuevo_nodo;              // <--- y aquí

    printf("Elemento %d agregado correctamente a la pila\n", n);
}
```

Y vemos al ejecutar que efectivamente la variable `pila` de `main()` resulta modificada como debe ser:

```
(nil)
Elemento 6 agregado correctamente a la pila
0x1761280
Elemento 12 agregado correctamente a la pila
0x17612a0
```

Answer (score 1):

> ¿hay alguna diferencia entre usar * y *& ?

Para saber la diferencia entre puntero (`*`) y referencia (`&`) te conviene leer [¿Cual es la diferencia entre `int *` e `int &`?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46909/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-int-e-int/46931#46931).

> No logro entender bien es que en el prototipo de la función le estoy pasando el *&

Sabemos que el puntero es un asterisco (`*`) y referencia es un et (`&`), así que `*&` es una referencia a puntero. Si leíste el hilo que enlacé, sabrás que una referencia (`&`) a efectos prácticos es indistinguible del objeto al que referencian, y es por eso que si quitas el et (`&`) el código sigue funcionando.

Podemos comprobarlo con este código de ejemplo:

```
#define MUESTRA(X) std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << '\n' \
        << '\t' << "Typeid: " << typeid(X).name() << '\n' \
        << '\t' << "Valor: " << X << '\n' \
        << '\t' << "Direccion: " << &X << '\n' \
        << '\t' << "Apunta a: " << *X << '\n'

void puntero(int *p)
{
    MUESTRA(p);
}

void referencia_puntero(int *&rp)
{
    MUESTRA(rp);
}

int main(int argc, char **)
{
    int *p = &argc;

    MUESTRA(p);

    puntero(p);
    referencia_puntero(p);

    return 0;
};
```

El código anterior [genera una salida parecida a esta](https://tio.run/##dY9dS8MwFIavm19x2KBfqHjdVmH4AV44QTfZxaCE9GwG2pNwlgoi/va6dJ1QsHd58z5vHqKsvVS1pH3XzTWpuq0QCm0OjlE2t0LMK9xpQnheP7ytXhfxJoGDq7JMmdZBUUBZPq6Xd6unl2VZ@hxtKYKtCIL@7CJ/N1t9WdRVBjOfXB@OD12RbDBOJlfvsjY8jDaT1L1mVEobGshwGl3YlpwEOZDpHynEp9EV@BrZxJocpDYR3yI4f9smufgZMMYdMpLSshwtQh5veBj5spGaekryXl2A@pAMadrjJxvcQOi7XIylIjg7fAr@cZ8oRtcywfXRmHfdLw) (he editado los valores de los punteros para mejor comprensión, en cada ejecución serán diferentes):

```
main
    Typeid: Pi
    Valor: 0x28
    Direccion: 0x18
    Apunta a: 1
puntero
    Typeid: Pi
    Valor: 0x28
    Direccion: 0xe8
    Apunta a: 1
referencia_puntero
    Typeid: Pi
    Valor: 0x28
    Direccion: 0x18
    Apunta a: 1
```

Vemos que el puntero `p` de `main` contiene la dirección `0x28` y está alojado en la dirección `0x18`, cuando lo pasamos a la función `puntero` su contenido es el mismo que en `main` (`0x28`) pero es un puntero diferente porque su dirección ha variado (antes `0x18`, ahora `0xe8`); pero cuando lo pasamos a la función `referencia_puntero` tanto el valor como la dirección es la misma que en `main`, a efectos prácticos la referencia a puntero es indistinguible del puntero original (como cualquier referencia a otros datos).

Dado que tanto en formato referencia a puntero como en formato puntero, el contenido del puntero no varía (`0x28`) es "*indiferente*" usar puntero (`*`) o referencia a puntero (`&*`) para este caso concreto.